# Get distinct values from mongodb array with Springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, distinct, spring-data-mongodb

I want to filter all collection from mongoDb document where duplicated elements are there in values field which is list. how we can get only unique data and it's named as group.
**My Collection:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4b3d44101cc8e202d30eaf"),
    "name" : "motorManufacturer",
    "values" : [ 
        "LEAM",  
        "Bico", 
        "Bico",  
        "LEAM"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4b3d44101cc8e202d30eaf"),
    "name" : "motorManufacturer",
    "values" : [ 
        "NOV", 
        "NOV"
        "SLB", 
        "SLB",
        "SD",
    ]
}
```

I have this Collection. I want only unique data from values in Spingboot.

**Expceted Result:**

```
{
    "name" : "motorManufacturer",
    "values" : [ 
        "Bico",  
        "LEAM"
    ]
}
{
    "name" : "motorManufacturer",
    "values" : [ 
        "NOV"
        "SLB",
        "SD",
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [$setUnion](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) to remove duplicates.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "name": 1,
      "values": {
        $setUnion: ["$values"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xrnGMI9I02E)

In spring-data-mongodb, this can be written as,

```
ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project().andInclude("name")
    .and(SetOperators.SetUnion.arrayAsSet("values")).as("values");

mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(projectStage), 
    <your collection class>.class, 
    <your collection class>.class).getMappedResults();
```